# Missing data and discriminant analysis

Tags: predictive-models, dataset, discriminant-analysis

I have a question. A company conducted a study in two countries using the same battery of questions. However, one question was left out in country B by mistake (the questions ranged in a scale from 1 to 5 and they were sort of: how important is for you to have a product that is reliable, meets my needs, etc.).

After the battery of questions was complete, discriminant analysis were used to compute membership to an attitudinal group (initial groups came from a previous study in a third country, and from this study, the coefficients of the discriminant were obtained for each question).

When people realised the mistake, they proposed three solutions:

- to take the mode of the other variables (there were 20 in total) and substitute the value of the missing question with that one for each person asked (this assumes lack of independence)
- to make the coefficients of the discriminant analysis to zero for that particular missing question
- to generate random numbers for this particular question for each person.

I wonder if any of these solutions actually make sense?

Comment: Two last options don't make much sense. The 1st one (replace by the within-respondent mean/median/mode) may be justified if all the questions are supposed to represent the same construct (factor, trait). Better way is to do imputation after you combine the 2 current countries or all 3 countries in one dataset. Multiple imputation is the most advanced choice. But EM single imputation is good too.